# Specify default theme for Veutify Input controls

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm learning Vue & Vuetify. Let's say I want to use the outline style on all my input fields. Is there a way that I can specify that at an application level so I don't have to add the "outline" attribute to every field in the application?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791902/vuetify-how-to-set-default-props).

Comment: I was looking into mixins and extensions prior to this post but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for finding this example, I'm going to try it with Vuetify.

Comment: Based on the recommendations in that post this is what I came up with, though it's not working. :(
https://codepen.io/asprich/pen/WBNgXM