# Extend vuetify VTextField

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to extend a vuetify `VTextField` component to create a reusable `password-field`. There are a number of props that control the component that we need to mutate. Vuejs considers prop mutation an "anti-pattern" and warnings against it.

I've experimented with declaring a computed-property that overrides the prop which works, but it tosses warnings in the web-console about the conflict.

Here is a simple example:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'password-field',
    mixins: [VTextField],
    data: () => ({
        reveal: false
    }),
    computed: {
        function type () {
            return this.reveal ? 'text' : 'password'
        }
    }
})
```

It feels like there should be away to use mixins to extend the VTextField and selectively drop the props we want to replace with computed-properties.  In the end, we need the value to be reactive and under the control of the `password-field` component -- *not* controlled by the parent.

Am I going the on the wrong direction here?

**UPDATED**

With the expert advice provided by [Yom S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3634538/yom-s) (), I was able to create a custom extension of `VTextField`. We went with his suggestion #2, an SFC templated component.

For anyone else who stumbles across this topic, here is the Typescript compatible implementation:

```
<!-- put this in components/password-field.vue -->
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind="computedProps"
    v-on:click:append="reveal = !reveal"
    v-on="listeners$"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  name: 'PasswordField',
  extends: VTextField,

  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Password'
    },
    rules: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [(v: string) => {
        return /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()?.]).{8,})/i.test(v) ||
          'At least 8 char; upper and lowercase, a number and a special char'
      }]
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    reveal: false
  }),

  computed: {
    computedProps: function () {
      return {
        ...this.$props,
        type: this.reveal ? 'text' : 'password',
        appendIcon: this.reveal ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'
      }
    }
  }

} as Vue.ComponentOptions<Vue>
</script>
```

Here's a simple example of how to use this component

```
<template>
  <v-form v-model="formValid">
    <password-field v-model="newPassword/>
    <v-btn :disabled="!formValid">Change</v-btn>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import PasswordField from '@/components/password-field.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ChangePasswordForm',
  data: () => ({
    formValid: false,
    newPassword: ''
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791902/vuetify-how-to-set-default-props

Comment: Thanks for the link...but it's not quite the answer. We can easily override the prop in our extension. The issue is we need it to be reactive and under control of the child component. This requires us to mutate prop, which can't/shouldn't be done.

Comment: I customized several Vuetify components for different purposes but not something like what you are trying to achieve. For my cases, I used computed props, but also props I passed as functions allowing the custom component to respond and act differently based on the list of props functions it gets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would've been helpful if this particular `type` prop was [`sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)-able; but since it's not, you could work around this by sort of re-rendering the `VTextField`, while also extending from it.

Now, I can't say this is the best solution as it has some drawbacks that make it a flawed wrapper. But it *does* get you what you need, as per your requirement in question.

Common cons:

- Scoped slots (e.g. `append`, `append-outer`) will not output the expected element(s).

---

So for this purpose, let's call this component "PasswordField", and we would use it like:

```html
<PasswordField 
  label="Enter your password"
  :revealed="revealed" 
  append-outer-icon="mdi-eye" 
  @click:append-outer="togglePassword" />
```

The `append-outer-icon` and the icon-toggling mechanism should probably be encapsulated within the component itself.

And here goes the implementation:

#### PasswordField.js

- Pros:

  - Somewhat simpler (as in no template necessary).
  - Faster compilation time, since it's just a JS file and won't have to go through the Vue template compiler and Vue Loader. (You could go further and make it a [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components)).
- Cons:

  - Event listeners don't seem to work.

```js
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
  name: 'PasswordField',
  extends: VTextField,

  props: {
    revealed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  render(h) {
    const { revealed, ...innerProps } = this.$options.propsData;

    return h(VTextField, {
      // For some reason this isn't effective
      listeners: this.$listeners,

      props: {
        ...innerProps,
        type: revealed ? 'text' : 'password'
      }
    })
  } 
}
```

Notice this [`extends`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) from the base component (`VTextField`) and sort of "overrides" the original `render` function, returning customized virtual node a.k.a. `VNode`.

However, as mentioned earlier, this has some drawback where it fails to listen to emitted events. (I would love to know if someone has a solution for this).

So, as a last resort, let's actually use a template and computed props, *literally* (we want the `props` part being the only properties to bind to, minus the `data`).

#### PasswordField.vue

- Pros:

  - More reliable, functionality-wise.
  - Event listeners will work as they should.
  - And of course, SFC works best this way.
- Cons:

  - Somewhat repetitive, in that you'd have to manually (re)bind props and register events.
  - Slower compilation time (should be hardly noticeable anyway).

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind="computedProps"
    v-on="$listeners">
  </v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
  import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib';

  export default {
    name: 'PasswordField',
    extends: VTextField,

    props: {
      revealed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },

    computed: {
      computedProps() {
        return {
          ...this.$props,
          type: this.revealed ? 'text' : 'password'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope that helps in some way!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks

Comment: This is a terrible idea fyi, you end up leaving all the original watchers and computed properties in place that may break things in fun and unexpected ways. Just wrap the original component (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064606/2074736), then anything extra you add has no chance of interfering with the original props.

Comment: @KaelWatts-Deuchar How exactly would that happen? Any verifiable example?

Comment: A different component but https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14411

Comment: @KaelWatts-Deuchar Would you help us make it less terrible and add some notes in this [official example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#extend-components) :) Also, could you explain why it works when extending from `Vue.options.components["VAutocomplete"]` (as seen in the example)?

Answer (score 0):

## Full code

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners" class="custom-class">
    <template
      v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)"
      :slot="slot"
      slot-scope="scope"
    >
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  extends: VTextField,

  props: {
    filled: { default: true },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

## Explanation

#### How to extend a vuetify compoent

Let's take an example for `v-text-field`

- in your script, import `VTextField` component:

```
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'
```

- extend your component from `VTextField`:

```
export default {
  extends: VBtn,
}
```

#### How To extend the Template?

- `v-bind="$props"` will bind all props
- `v-on="$listeners"` will bind all events
- looping over `$scopedSlots` and redefine all scoped slots

example:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners">
    <template
      v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)"
      :slot="slot"
      slot-scope="scope"
    >
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
</template>
```

now you can add your custom classes, override template, or anything else.

### How to override default props:

- redefine your props in `props` object and add a default value for them

example to make text field filled by default:

```
props: {
    filled: { default: true },
  }
```