# vuetify extend component throw Unexpected token 'export' on nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

I try to extend v-textfield component in my nuxt project.

I create a UiTextField.vue component like that:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-bind="computedProps" v-on="$listeners" outlined>
  </v-text-field>
</template> 

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { VTextField } from "vuetify/lib";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "UiTextField",
  extends: VTextField,

  props: {
    customProps: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    computedProps() {
      return {
        ...this.$props,
      };
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

But nuxt return "Unexpected token 'export'".

I follow this topic to create my component: [Extend vuetify VTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479853/extend-vuetify-vtextfield)

Comment: Add `'vuetify/lib'` to the [`transpile`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#transpile) array in your `nuxt.config.js` file

Comment: Thank's it working now. Maybe you can add your comment as answer so I can validate it !